# RMI and server with multiple Threads

Tags: java, rmi

So, I'm making a simple program that uses RMI so that "clients" can try to read or write in a file. But I want the server to run in multiple threads so that it can accommodate multiple requests from multiple  clients.

I'm aware that the server side may or may not run in  multiple threads, like it says [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch3.html). But is there anyway to create multiple threads to manage the clients requests, with lines semaphores and maybe even method priority ?

Thanks

Comment: RMI protocol is already multihreaded. So you only need to take care of syncronization further on, like writhing to file.

Comment: @MladenSavić All the Java RMI implementations known to me are multi-threaded. However this is not a property of either the protocol or the specification.Protocols are not multithreaded. *Implementations* are multi-threaded. The RMI Specification carefully makes no guarantees about the relationship between client and server threads. The occult meaning of this is that you cannot assume it is single-threaded.